# self.iface.mapCanvas().destinationCrs() Replacement in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, migration

I need to store the map canvas' destinationCrs in a variable, but when using the following line:

```
self.iface.mapCanvas().destinationCrs()
```

I get the error:

> 'QgsMapCanvas' object has no attribute 'destinationCrs'

What is the appropriate replacement for this function in QGIS 3.x?

SOLUTION:  The REAL issue was omitting the MapRenderer() instead of replacing it with mapSettings(), which appears to have resolved the dilemma.

Original (QGIS 2) code:

```
    map_crs = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().destinationCrs()
```

New (QGIS 3) code:

```
    map_crs = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().destinationCrs()
```

Comment: but, what is the question?

Comment: @Fran - the question was "What is the appropriate replacement for this function in QGIS 3.x?" where "this function" = `self.iface.mapCanvas().destinationCrs()`.  As stated in the ADDENDUM, "this function" should have been `self.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().destinationCrs()` but I mistakenly deleted `mapRenderer()` in my troubleshooting.  `mapRenderer()` was replaced by `mapSettings()` in QGIS 3.  Once I had the correct line of code to troubleshoot, finding the answer was much simpler.

Comment: mmm..okey!the solution is `iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().destinationCrs()` then.  QgsMapRenderer. It has been replaced by QgsMapRendererJob with subclasses and QgsMapSettings.

Comment: Updated post to indicate the solution was found.

Comment: This comment led to my solution. I can answer my own question (as I sort of did in the edit) or you can post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put my comment as an answer
 `iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().destinationCrs()`

**QgsMapRenderer** has been replaced by **QgsMapRendererJob** with subclasses and **QgsMapSettings**.